# Proving combinatorial identity involving counting multisets

Tags: combinatorics

$ \textbf{Question}: $ Let $ n $ and $ k $ be nonnegative integers such that $ n \ge 1, $ then 
$$ \displaystyle \binom{n - 1}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n + 1}{2} + \dots + \binom{n + k - 1}{k} = \binom{n + k}{k} \; \; \; \; \; \; \; (\ast) $$

I ran into this problem while trying to prove the formula involving counting [multisets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) In general, the number of ways to form $ k $-elements multisets from an $ n $-elements set, denoted by $ M(n, k) $ where $ n \ge 1, $ is $ \displaystyle \binom{n + k - 1}{k}. $ I am attempting to prove this fact using proof by strong induction on $ n, $ which eventually leads to proving that $ (\ast) $ is true, but I currently stuck on proving $ (\ast). $ Can someone provide me some hints to tackle $ (\ast)? $

Also, $ (\ast) $ implies that $ \displaystyle M(n + 1, k) = \sum_{i = 0}^{k} \; M(n, i). $

Comment: This is the hockey stick identity.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin How so? I found the identity you mention here (http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity) but it doesn't seem to match the formula in $ (\ast) $

Comment: $\text{Your expression} = {n-1 \choose n-1} + {n \choose n-1} + {n+1 \choose n-1} + \ldots + {n+k-1 \choose n-1}$ so your $n-1$ is that page's $r$ and their $n$ is your $n+k-1$.

Comment: Oh yes thank you for pointing that out! I actually used that identity you mentioned earlier in my induction proof to arrive at $ (\ast), $ but this time I didn't recognize that identity.

Comment: yeah, you had your last line of the post right there since the beginning, which of course is another equivalent form.

Answer (score 1):

The left hand side is the coefficient of $x^k$ in 
\begin{align*}
x^k(1+x)^{n-1}+x^{k-1}(1+x)^n &+ \cdots + (1+x)^{n+k-1} = x^k(1+x)^{n-1}\frac{\left(1-\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)^{k+1}\right)}{1-\frac{1+x}{x}}\\
&=x^k(1+x)^{n-1}\frac{(1+x)^{k+1}-x^{k+1}}{x^{k}}\\
&= (1+x)^{n+k} - x^{k+1}(1+x)^{n-1}
\end{align*}
and hence equals $\binom{n+k}{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

So $$\binom{n+k}{k}=\binom{n+(k+1)-1}{(k+1)-1}$$ which is the number of ways to create $n$ with $k+1$ summands(allowing $0$ as a summand).

So, lets denote $A_{n,k+1}$ the sets of those tuples(each elements in the tuple is like a summand).

So, you have to prove that $A_{n,k+1}=\phi(\bigcup _{i=0}^k A_{n-1,i+1})$ where $\phi$ is defined as $\phi ((x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_r))=(x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_r+1,\underbrace {0,\ldots ,0}_{\text{$k+1-r$ times}})$. By adding principle, you will get your resut.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $\binom{n-1+i}i=\binom{n-1+i}{n-1}$ is the number of $n$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n+k\}$ whose largest element is $n+i$. What is $\binom{n+k}n$?